# Is "he will be come around 1pm" or "he will come around 1pm" more formal?

Tags: formal-language, formality

I would like to know which sentence is more formal in "he will be come around 1pm on tomorrow afternoon" and "he will come around 1pm on tomorrow afternoon"

Comment: teacher, i would like to know which is more formal.

Comment: To use 'be' with come or gone is archaic, more so with 'come'.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a 'be' verb, the verb you're pairing with it has to change into the -ing form.  So your two options should be:

- "He *will come* around 1pm tomorrow"
- "He *will be coming* around 1pm tomorrow"

I don't think either one is more formal than the other; rather, they say slightly different things.

"He will come" is the future tense. "He will be coming" is the future-progressive (or future-continuous) tense. They're very similar, and most people will understand you perfectly whichever one you use, but if you're being very formal, the first is for events that will happen at a specific point in time, while the second is for events that will start at some point in the future and continue for an expected duration.

Since going to a place is an ongoing action, it should be described using the progressive form.  If you want to use the future tense, you should use a verb that describes a specific moment in time.  In this case, "He will arrive around 1pm tomorrow" would be more correct than "he will come". So I guess by that measure, the second option is 'more formal'.

Comment: In the same way you could say, *"He will **be arriving** around 1pm tomorrow"*.  I agree there's not much difference in formality there.  If you really want to make it formal, you would do something like adding an honorific, *"**The gentleman** will arrive around 1pm tomorrow,"* or various other methods.